# Timeout expired with SQL Server insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to insert 200,000 documents from a folder into the SQL Server database into a `varbinary` column. I get a timeout expiration message after inserting 80,000 documents. Average file size is about 250kb and max file size is 50MB. I am running this c# program on the server where the database is located.

Please suggest.

The error:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The code:

```
string spath = @"c:\documents";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(spath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Console.Write("Files Count:" + files.Length);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  con.Open();
  string insertSQL = "INSERT INTO table_Temp(doc_content, doc_path) values(@File, @path)";

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
  var pFile = cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
  var pPath = cmd.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.Text);

  var tran = con.BeginTransaction();
  var fn = 0;

  foreach (string docPath in files)
  {
    string newPath = docPath.Remove(0, spath.Length);

    string archive = new DirectoryInfo(docPath).Parent.Name;
    fn += 1;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      pFile.Value = stream;
      pPath.Value = newPath;

      cmd.Transaction = tran;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      if (fn % 10 == 0)
      {
        tran.Commit();
        tran = con.BeginTransaction();
        Console.Write("|");
      }

      Console.Write(".");
    }
  }

  tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: 50MB is a might large file to shove into a table like this. No surprise it timed out. The default timeout is only 30 seconds. Those 50MB files could easily blow that away. Either increase the timeout or find a different storage solution.

Comment: Also, leave only one BeginTransaction and one Commit. It makes no sense opening a transaction, executing a single insert and then committing

Comment: where do I increase a timeout? you mean sqlcommand object timeout?

Comment: Yes on the command object.

Comment: @Steve with 200,000 inserts it would be a horrible idea to do this entire group as a single transaction. The size of that transaction would decimate the transaction log and possibly run out of disc space as the size of tempdb becomes massive. Since every insert is already in an implicit transaction this is actually not doing anything one way or the other.

Comment: @nav100 you would modify the timeout on the `SqlConnection` object. According to MSDN, the default timeout is 15 seconds.

Comment: Have you considered using a table-valued-parameter instead of doing it row by row? You may still have issues given the size of the data, but at least you wouldn't have to be treating each of the 200,000 rows as a distinct operation. You could batch them by maybe 1000 at a time

Comment: For something like this i would look into SQLBulkCopy.  You can build a local table in your app identical to the one your loading and batch push them to the server.  SQLBulkCopy has easy timeout managment as well.

Comment: @SeanLange, while doing 200,000 inserts in a single transaction may be a bad idea, it would be for potential locking issues, not for filling up the log. If the database is in Full Recovery mode, then every insert, regardless of transaction type or duration, will be written to the log and not cleared out until the log is backed up. If the database is in Simple mode, then yes, it will be cleared out after every insert.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would suggest using [SQLBulkCopy](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1043626/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-csharp) methods, since it should be able to handle data insertion much more easily. Further, as others have pointed out, you might want to increase the timeout condition for your command.

Answer (score 0):

While I would agree this may be best for a bulk copy of some sort, if you must do this in the c# program, your only option is probably to increase the timeout value. You can do this after your `SqlCommand` object has been created via `cmd.CommandTimeout = <new timeout>;` The property `CommandTimeout` is an integer representing the number seconds for the timeout, or zero if you never want it to timeout.

See the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.1) for details

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the timeout for the transaction directly on that object in your application code, this way you are not changing sql server settings.

Secondly, you can build batches in your application also.  You say you can get 80k docs before a timeout, set your batch size at 50k, process them, commit them, grab the next batch.  Having your application manage batching also allows you to catch sql errors, such as timeout, and then dynamically adjust the batch size and retry without ever crashing.  This is the entire reason for writing your application in the first place, other wise you could just use the wizard in management studio and manually insert your files.

I highly recommend batching over other options.

@Shubham Pandey also provides a great link to SQL bulk copy info, which also has links to more info.  You should definitely experiment with the bulk copy class and see if you can get additional gains with it as well.